# $\int_{-2}^xf(t)dt$ for $f(t) = \tiny\begin{cases} -1 \, &t<0 \\ 1 \, &t\ge 0 \end{cases} $, and its limit at $x=0$

Tags: continuity, problem-solving, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f: [-2,2] \to \mathbb R$, $$
f(t) = 
\begin{cases}
-1 \, &t<0 \\
1 \, &t\ge 0
\end{cases}
$$

Define $g:  [-2,2] \to \mathbb R$ as:
$$g(x) = \int_{-2}^xf(t)dt$$

Plot $g(x)$ and find it's limit at 0.

Based on my reading from Wiki, I need to check whether the function is Riemann integrable (which it should be based on graphical intuition). The doubt is that there is only one sub-interval, of some given partition, due to which the lower and upper Darboux sums will not match.

But how do I show in the limit they are same?

---

EDIT: Based on learnings from various comments, another attempt:

For a given $x \ge 0$, consider the partition of $[-2,x]$ in $2n$ parts such that all the sub-intervals in $[-2,0]$ are of equal length $2/n$ and the rest of the partitions are of length $x/n$. Call this partition $P$.

\begin{align}
U(P,f,x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg[(n-1)\frac{2}{n}(-1) + \frac{2}{n}(1) + (n-1)\frac{x}{n}(1)\bigg] \\
&=x-2 \\
L(P,f,x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg[(n\frac{2}{n}(-1) + \frac{2}{n}(1) + (n-1)\frac{x}{n}(1)\bigg] \\
&= x-2
\end{align}

For $x<0$, $f(x)$ is continuous so $g(x)$ is well defined and is $-2-x$.

As shown above, since in the limit Darboux sums are same, $g(x)$ is defined and is equal to the limit of the Darboux sum. Which gives:

$$g(x) = |x|-2$$

Is this the right approach?

---

EDIT 2:
In terms of $\epsilon$:

Let $P$ be defined in the same way except that $n>4/\epsilon$. Now, for $P$,

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = 4/n < \epsilon$$

So for any $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \,\, P$, such that $U=L$

Comment: They won't be the same, but they can be arbitrarily close given the right partition. Try dividing it to $n$ equal parts, and pick a large enough $n$.

Comment: $f$ is monotonic, hence Riemann integrable.

Comment: Show that $g(x)=|x|-2$.

Comment: @Gary: I was able to show this graphically but couldn't derive. My doubt is that how do I show this?

Comment: @Fred: I can perhaps see this intuitively but could you please guide me to the proof of this?

Comment: @Oria: that sounds like a good way...for 2n equal parts $U=(n-1)2/n*(-1)+(n+1)*2/n*1 $and $L=n*2/n*(-1)+n*2/n*1. So for large n both are 0. But how do I use this?

Comment: @Dayne all subintervals but one don't contribute to both of the darboux sums, and the one who does contributes 2 times it's length. Therefore, given $\epsilon >0$, pick $n>2/ \epsilon$ and that should do it.

Comment: @Oria, I think you mean $n>\frac8\varepsilon$ because the step is $h=\frac4n$ on a closed interval of length $4$ times that of the unit segment.

Comment: @Invisible: I have posted another attempt. Do you think this is right?

Comment: @Oria: based on your suggestion, I have made an attempt and added that to the question.

Comment: @Invisible you are correct. I didn't do the calculations, just wanted to give the OP the feel of the proof

Comment: Dayne, very good attempt! (+1) I don't think you need the part on the bottom, because you haven't found a partition s. t. $U=L$. For a given $\varepsilon>0$, you (found all but finitely many partitions into $2n$ part for which $U$ and $L$ become closer and closer as $n\to\infty)*$ and you should take the step $h=\frac{b−a}n=\frac4n$ in this case. :) $(*)$ You actually need an $\color{red}{\boldsymbol{\text{ odd }}}$ number of subintervals because $0$ shouldn't be the boundary of any. The total length is even and then you end up with something as you had in the very beginning.